# Restaurant value or restaurant's value

Tags: word-choice, possessives

I'm confused.
What is another way to say "the value of the restaurant" or "the target audience of the restaurant"?
Is it ok to say "restaurant's value or restaurant's target audience?" or it is better not to use 's (restaurant value or restaurant target audience)?

Comment: What do you mean by the value of a restaurant? How much is paid for the business?

Comment: Here "value" in meaning "why customers come to a particular restaurant, what is important to them"

Answer (score 1):

You can use *the restaurant's value* or *the value of the restaurant*.

*Restaurant value* is grammatical, but an unlikely expression, because it refers to a kind of value that is somehow related to restaurants or a restaurant. It doesn't mean the value of a particular restaurant, except perhaps in a specialized context where you talking about different kinds of value, But even in that context, it's not clear what you might mean by *restaurant value*.

Comment: Thank you)) I'm confused because I have read that possessive nouns can't be used with inanimate objects

Comment: They are less used with inanimates, but there is not a sharp distinction. I think that human organisations (like business, shops, societies, restaurants) get a sort of "noorary animacy" for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you so much)))

Comment: You can certainly use possessives with inanimate objects, and this is absolutely normal. The sea's surface, the tree's leaves, the sun's rays, the egg's shell, the needle's point.

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me a lot))

Comment: What is noorary animacy?

Comment: Sorry. I meant "honorary". But in vew of Michael's comment I'm not sure it's helpful even then.